# Net Change of Owners’ Equity

Tags: accounting

I have a question related to **Net Change of Owners’ Equity** especially when the company is buying back the stocks that they shared to the investor before. How the change are affecting to the assets and equity?

Answer (score 1):

Buying back stock decreases assets and decreases equity. Whether the **Net** change in owner's equity is net of *buybacks* and *issuances* is another question, and would need to be defined by whoever is publishing that metric.

Answer (score -1):

As I now understand it, this should balance out. Buying stock back is essentially paying off a loan that was secured with partial ownership of the company. Money goes out, which would lower the value of the company, but the company now has fewer owners so the value of shares remaining in circulation goes up by about the same amount (assuming they repurchased the shares at the current price).

Companies repurchase shares for many reasons. One reason my own employer did so on a regular basis was so they had shares to offer through the Employee Stock Purchase Plan.